# expected fi bug in bash script

Tags: bash

The following bash script creates a directory if not exists and writes a file to it. Now, if directory exists, it retrieves a list of files of this directory encapsulated in an array. This is the code:

```
if [ -d $ETC_DIR ]; then
    echo " * wan27 has been found on your system"
    echo " * checking for installed versions"
    versions=( `ls $ETC_DIR` ) # line 27
else
    echo " * First time installation! Creating etc directory now..."
    mkdir $ETC_DIR
    echo "$VERSION\n$USERi\n`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`\n$ROOT_DIR" > $ETC_DIR/install_$VERSION.txt
fi
```

And this is what the terminal outputs:

```
27: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

So, line 27 actually is this one in first excerpt of code:

```
versions=( `ls $ETC_DIR` )
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried added semi-colons as well but ended up with the same result...

Comment: you should include line 1~23 as well

Comment: You ought to be saying `versions=( $ETC_DIR/* )` instead of relying on the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script relies on a Bash feature (creating an array using assignment with parentheses), but it's being run by the Bourne shell.

Change the first line of your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: yes, that did the trick! I've also replace line 27 by versions=$(ls $ETC_DIR)